# How to define a constant once for both Rust and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, rust, dry

I'm working on a client-server app, with React/Javascript in the browser talking to a cloud-based smart contract written in Rust.  I need both halves of the app to agree on a set of symbols and their (integer) values.  Nothing too complicated, just stuff like BOB=1, JANE=2, FRED=3, and so on.

Right now I've defined this set of symbols twice: once in a rust file "constants.rs" that gets compiled in the smart contract, and once in a javascript file "constants.js" that gets included in the React app by the bundler.

That works for prototyping, but I foresee that this list of contracts could get quite large and be updated fairly often.  I don't want to have to manually double-check that the rust file and the js file are defining everything the same way.  But if they ever got out of sync it could lead to weird bugs.

What is the DRY way to write this just once -- in Rust, Javascript or any other format -- and then generate both constants.rs and constants.js from that?

Comment: I would just write a build script that generates the files, use your favourite language to build

Comment: As a alternative, you might consider using a JSON or YAML file with all the constants, added as a shared dependency.

Comment: what @raina77ow said. I think JSON might be easiest, here, since one side is JS and you can import JSON directly. Then you can either write a program to generate constants.rs or have your rust program parse your constants.json file at runtime.